# String join in JScript?

Tags: string, wsh, jscript

How do I join a bunch of strings with a separator in JScript?

(I'm looking for a solution with linear running time.)

Comment: Do you have them in an array? Why don't you use `array.join('separater')`?

Comment: Do not concat strings using += it's slower than the array/join methods below.

Comment: ...reason being that strings in JScript cannot really be concatenated. The JScript engine has to create a brand new string every time you concatenate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like the `join()` method? =D

```
var elements = ["1", "2", "3"];
var joinedString = elements.join(',');
```

Comment: WHOA you can do that?? Why the heck is it an array method?? wow, nice, thanks!

Comment: Because it is joining the elements of an array.

Answer (score 3):

Somthing like this:

```
['a', 'b', 'c'].join(',');
```

However, for small number of strings, `+` operator will also do fine (and may do better depending on circumstances). Here's a nice [article](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-fast-string-concatenation/) comparing the 2 approaches.

And a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/string-concatenation/3) page for the skeptics.

Answer (score 2):

You can use join on an array.

```
var strArray = [
    "test1",
    "test2",
    "test3"
];

var output = strArray.join(", ");
```

Here's a jsperf test of a couple different methods here: http://jsperf.com/joining-strings.  Join is definitely the fastest of the ways I tried, by at least 3x (in Chrome).

You'll have to try out the jsperf yourself and/or change it to model exactly what you care about.  To my surprise, Firefox 6 and Safari 5 are faster just adding a bunch of strings together than using `.join()`.

You said you're looking for a solution with `linear` running time.  I presume that means that when you double the number of strings, the performance is no worse than double.  That means you'd have to test a bunch of different cases and see which technique was closest to linear performance.  The [first jsperf](http://jsperf.com/joining-strings) was concatenating 9 strings with separators between them.  So, I wrote a [second jsperf](http://jsperf.com/joining-strings2) that was concatenating 18 strings with separators between them.  None of the techniques were quite linear in Chrome.  Oddly enough, the for loop += method which is the slowest overall was closest to linear.  So, I think you have to decide whether you want fast or linear.  The slowest method I tried is the closest to linear, but it's still slow.  If you're concatenating really large numbers of strings, then you'd have to test that specific case to see which one wins for either linearity or overall performance.